# Using jQuery can you select a set of siblings based on a number?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, siblings

Example:

```
<span>Bacon, Chris P.</span>
<span>Jones, Pete</span>
<span>Adams, Sam</span>
<span>Bacon, Chris P.</span>
<span>Jones, Pete</span>
<span>Adams, Sam</span>
<span>Bacon, Chris P.</span>
```

Using `eq()` to choose where to start, how can one use jQuery to select an arbitrary number of siblings? Such as `span:eq(0)` through `span:eq(10)`?

Comment: Which siblings do you want, exactly?

Comment: Next siblings? Previous siblings? Combination of both?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery `slice()`:

```
$('<span>').slice(1, 10);
```

**or** you can use the `:gt()` selector combined with the `:lt()` selector:

```
$('<span>:gt(0):lt(10)'); // first 10 elements
```

Docs:

- http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/
- http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/
- http://api.jquery.com/slice/

Comment: I think he is looking for siblings, not characters in the individual span.

Comment: slice whatever you want, depends on which you want to select

Comment: Hey, sorry, I was confused.  I didn't know jQuery had a slice() filter.  I thought you were referring to just the javascript slice() command.  It is a minor difference in text, but a major difference in outcome.

Answer (score 5):

You could use `nextUntil()`:

```
$('span:eq(2)').nextUntil( $('span:eq(6)') ).addBack()
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/DNTBh/1/)**